# ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote hostとなりvagrant sshできなくなった

Tags: vagrant

■環境
centos7.0

■エラーメッセージ
・vagrant up時

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'chef/centos-7.0' is up to date...
==> default: There was a problem while downloading the metadata for your box
==> default: to check for updates. This is not an error, since it is usually due
==> default: to temporary network problems. This is just a warning. The problem
==> default: encountered was:
==> default:
==> default: The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
==> default:
==> default: If you want to check for box updates, verify your network connection
==> default: is valid and try again.
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 8000 => 12345 (adapter 1)
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
```

・vagrant ssh時

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

■hosts.allow

```
ALL : 127.0.0.1
sshd : ALL
```

known_hostsは削除済みです。作業しているなかで突然このような状態になりました。
解決策をご教示いただけませんでしょうか。

CentOS7はvirtualBoxの中に立ち上げたゲストOSです。

---

`ssh -vvv -p 2222 -i ~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key -l vagrant 127.0.0.1`
を実行したところ、下記のメッセージが出ました。
どのように対処すればよいでしょうか？

```
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/mae/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 127.0.0.1 [127.0.0.1] port 2222.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mae/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mae/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/mae/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mae/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Comment: `ssh`のデバッグログにヒントがあるかもしれません。お使いのホストOSがわからないので、私の環境(ubuntu 15.10)で確認できた範囲の話になりますが、他のOSであれば何とか置き換えて試してみてください。まずは`ssh -p 2222 -i ~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key -l vagrant 127.0.0.1`とし実行します。`~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key`の部分は単純に`insecure_private_key`という`vagrant`がデフォルトで使う秘密鍵ファイルです。もしこれでssh処理中にパスワードを聞かれるようでしたら秘密鍵ファイルが自動で置き換えられています（セキュリティの理由から最初のブート時にそういう動作をしてるそうです)。この場合、その秘密鍵の場所を`vagrant ssh-config`というコマンドで知ることができます。表示される`IdentityFile`という項目にファイルのパスが示されますので、今度はそのパスを使って`ssh -vvv -p 2222 -i <秘密鍵のパス> -l vagrant 127.0.0.1`と実行してください。これで公開鍵認証時のエラーであれば何かしらデバッグログに出るはずです。そのログの中にヒントが見つかるかもしれません。

Comment: ホストOSとゲストOSの環境がよく分かりません。CentOS7はvagrant実行側(ホスト)ですか？それともvirtual box等で作成して、これからログインしようとしている側のOS(ゲスト)のことですか？そのへんも質問の中に書いてください。(回答でないことを回答として追加せず、できるだけ質問を編集して対応してください。）

Answer (score 0):

手元の環境(`ubuntu 15.10`)からゲストOS(`CentOS 6.7`)`ssh`が成功する場合のログと見比べていますが、`ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`の例の行まではほぼ同じみたいです。

```
$ vagrant up
...
...
(ゲストOSが起動してからvagrantがsshアクセスに使う秘密鍵を調べる)
$ vagrant ssh-config
Host www
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2222
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile /home/cul8er/xxxx/.vagrant/machines/www/virtualbox/private_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
$ ssh -vvv -p 2222 -l vagrant -i /home/cul8er/xxxx/.vagrant/machines/www/virtualbox/private_key 127.0.0.1
OpenSSH_6.9p1 Ubuntu-2, OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/cul8er/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 127.0.0.1 [127.0.0.1] port 2222.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/cul8er/xxxx/.vagrant/machines/www/virtualbox/private_key type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/cul8er/xxxx/.vagrant/machines/www/virtualbox/private_key-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9p1 Ubuntu-2

<ここまでのログは質問の起きた状況とほぼ同じ見える>

debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 127.0.0.1:2222 as 'vagrant'
...
...
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/cul8er/xxxx/.vagrant/machines/www/virtualbox/private_key
...
...
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 127.0.0.1 ([127.0.0.1]:2222).
...
...
```

幾つかのウェブページの説明ではこのエラーは複数の原因があるようですね。
中でも[ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host](http://edoceo.com/notabene/ssh-exchange-identification)というページに比較的網羅的な説明があったので紹介します。

- リモートサーバー（この質問で言うとゲストマシン側)の`hosts.allow`と`hosts.deny`のどちらかまたは両方に接続制御がかかっている場合
- サーバーの過負荷：ログインしようとしているサーバーで`sshd`に関連する大量のゾンビプロセスがあって接続最大数に達したなどの場合
- フィンガープリントの情報が何かしらのきっかけで壊れてしまった場合。`~/.ssh/known_hosts`の中身を消したり、サーバー側の公開鍵ファイル(`authorized_keys`)を作り直したりして対応することがあるらしい他、`/etc/ssh/*key*`がない状態でsshdが再起動されていないときにもエラーの発生事例があるらしい
- `glibc`や`openssl`のアップグレード後に`ssh`/`sshd`との依存関係が壊れてしまった場合

ご参考になれば。

Comment: vagrant up してから実際にvagrant ssh で自動ログインする際に使われている秘密鍵の場所を調べてから、手動でsshログインを試みるまでの手順が分かるように編集しました。

Answer (score 0):

当方では、Vagrant 1.5で作ったBoxをVagrant 1.7.4環境において`vagrant up`でゲストOS生成後、`vagrant package`でBoxを作り、そのBoxから再度Vagrant 1.7.4環境で`vagrant up`したとき、SSH秘密鍵のパスがBox内部の秘密鍵から`~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key`に変更になり、`vagrant up`にてSSHのタイムアウトエラーが出るようになりました。

現象としては、Vagrant 1.7より採用された、安全でない鍵ペアを使っているBoxとゲストOSの鍵ペアを置換する機能のために、まずは安全でない鍵ペアでのログインが試みられていて、手元の環境に存在するVagrant配布物に含まれる**秘匿されていない秘密鍵**`~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key`に対応する公開鍵が、ゲストOSの`~/.ssh/authorized_keys`に存在しないということだと思います。

解決法としては、手元の環境で秘密鍵に対応する公開鍵を作成（この公開鍵はネットで事実上公開されているので https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/tree/master/keys マスクしません）

```sh
$ ssh-keygen.exe -y -f ~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEA6NF8iallvQVp22WDkTkyrtvp9eWW6A8YVr+kz4TjGYe7gHzIw+niNltGEFHzD8+v1I2YJ6oXevct1YeS0o9HZyN1Q9qgCgzUFtdOKLv6IedplqoPkcmF0aYet2PkEDo3MlTBckFXPITAMzF8dJSIFo9D8HfdOV0IAdx4O7PtixWKn5y2hMNG0zQPyUecp4pzC6kivAIhyfHilFR61RGL+GPXQ2MWZWFYbAGjyiYJnAmCP3NOTd0jMZEnDkbUvxhMmBYSdETk1rRgm+R4LOzFUGaHqHDLKLX+FIPKcF96hrucXzcWyLbIbEgE98OHlnVYCzRdK8jlqm8tehUc9c9WhQ==
```

として公開鍵を生成した後、ゲストOSのLinuxに`vagrant`ユーザでパスワードログインをして、先ほどの公開鍵を

```sh
$ cat << 'EOS' >>  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEA6NF8iallvQVp22WDkTkyrtvp9eWW6A8YVr+kz4TjGYe7gHzIw+niNltGEFHzD8+v1I2YJ6oXevct1YeS0o9HZyN1Q9qgCgzUFtdOKLv6IedplqoPkcmF0aYet2PkEDo3MlTBckFXPITAMzF8dJSIFo9D8HfdOV0IAdx4O7PtixWKn5y2hMNG0zQPyUecp4pzC6kivAIhyfHilFR61RGL+GPXQ2MWZWFYbAGjyiYJnAmCP3NOTd0jMZEnDkbUvxhMmBYSdETk1rRgm+R4LOzFUGaHqHDLKLX+FIPKcF96hrucXzcWyLbIbEgE98OHlnVYCzRdK8jlqm8tehUc9c9WhQ== vagrant insecure public key
EOS
```

で、ゲストOSの`vagrant`ユーザの公開鍵認証SSHログインができるように登録します。

その後、ゲストOSを抜けた後、`vagrant halt`をすると、

```sh
$ vagrant halt
==> default: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
    default:
    default: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace
    default: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
    default:
    default: Inserting generated public key within guest...
    default: Removing insecure key from the guest if its present...
    default: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
```

と表示され、`vagrant ssh`用の新しい鍵ペアが生成・置換されます。

以降、正常に`vagrant up`できるようになると思います。

Comment: CLCLさん、ご回答ありがとうございます。
大変恐縮なのですが、vagrantへのパスワードログインはどのように行えばよいでしょうか？ `vagrant ssh`では以下のエラーメッセージがでてしまいます。
`ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`

Comment: 元のBoxの作り方にもよるかもしれませんが、``vagrant up``後エラーがさんざんで終わってプロンプトに戻った後、

``ssh -p 2222 -l vagrant 127.0.0.1``

で、パスワードは``vagrant``で入れるかと思います。

でも、私のときは、``vagrant ssh``実行時、公開鍵認証に失敗した後自動的にパスワード認証に切り替わったので、なんか動きが違うかもしれません。

Answer (score 0):

先日私もハマったのですが、ゲストOSにsshがインストールされてない可能性はないですか??

Vagrantfileを以下のように編集してvagrant upするとGUIが起動するので、そこ画面でID/PASSともにvagrantでログインして、sshコマンドがインストールされてるかどうか試していただきたいです。もしインストールされてなければ、そもそもsshできないのでvagrant sshもこけてしまいます。

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
#   # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
  vb.gui = true
#
#   # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
#   vb.memory = "1024"
end
```

あ、「突然このようになった」て書いてありますね、前はできたということなら、↑の可能性はないと思います。